# how to change CATALINA_BASE in /var/lib/tomcat6 in ubuntu 10.4

Tags: tomcat6, ubuntu-10.04

i install tomcat6 on ubuntu 10.4 but i want to save my projects in different directory than this CATALINA_BASE in /var/lib/tomcat6 any one can help me in this

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you:
http://www.udel.edu/CIS/474/pconrad/06S/topics/tomcat/generalInstallAdvice/sharedInstall.txt

try to change the env variables like

```
setenv CATALINA_BASE /home/path/to/dir
```

I didn't try this myself, so tell me if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have a different version of Tomcat, but I was able to fix this given a tip found in `catalina.sh`:

> Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script **setenv.sh** in `$CATALINA_BASE/bin` to keep your customizations separate.